# Как в Selenium Chrome проверить что DOM страницы загружен?

Tags: c#, wpf, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Тренируюсь с Selenium на языке C# и возник вопрос.
Как написать условия для проверки что DOM страницы загружен?
Если DOM страницы не загружен показать сообщение.

```
MessageBox.Show("Страница не загружена");
```

Сейчас у меня такой код:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace WpfSelenium_1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ChromeDriverService chromeservice = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            chromeservice.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;  //спрятать консоль 

            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeservice);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://mssitetester.com");
            MessageBox.Show("ok");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45234078/12888024